# Why doesn’t small have a regular adverbial form?

Tags: adverbs, irregular

Loud => loudly
Soft => softly
Large => largely
Small => ???

Comment: Careful, loudly and softly are not analogous to largely, which has another meaning: overall. He cut the pieces of cake small. [adverb].

Comment: The answer to a "why" question about a language is almost always "because that's the way it is". Languages are almost never designed or planned: they just happen.

Comment: And zero-derived adverbs are common in English. As well as _cut it small_ (that @Lambie mentions), _play it loud_ and _write it large_ are normal.

Comment: @ColinFine yeah but there’s still oftentimes a reason, like “small is from Greek but the ly adverbial suffix is only used for Latin adjectives.”

Comment: Or some other mechanism or principle at play that can at least deepen one’s understanding.

Comment: You speak in a loud way, but you don't cut something up in a small way, only into small pieces. _Small_ doesn't need an adverb of the same kind.

Comment: @Lambie No, *small* is an adjective there, functioning as a predicative.

Comment: How he cut the pieces, Small. Adverb.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I never trust "functioning as".

Comment: @Lambie Me neither. I should have said "with the function of". Cut them small, thin, square. Those look like adjectives don't they?

Comment: @Lambie - _Small_ describes the resulting pieces, not the manner of cutting.

Comment: Merriam Webster: small

2 of 3
adverb
1
: in or into small pieces
2
: without force or loudness
speak as small as you will
—William Shakespeare
3
: in a small manner

Comment: Also, dictionary.com : adverb: in a small manner:
They talked big but lived small.
into small pieces:
Slice the cake small. :)

Comment: Few would take 'small' as an adverb of manner; most would interpret 'He cut the pieces of cake small' as a resultative predication, as with 'she hammered the metal flat' / 'they painted the town red'. // 'He shot wide' is far more open to interpretation (adverb of [unintended?] manner? Resultative state?)

Comment: Yes: in "He cut the cake small", "small" is not an an adverb functioning as an adjunct of manner but an adjective functioning as resultative predicative complement describing the pieces.

Comment: This question should remain closed as "smally" has been an adverb in English since the 14th century: *1340 "Me ssel recordi zueteliche and smalliche be little stechches alle þe guodnesses of oure lhorde." Ayenbite (1866) 111 (Middle English Dictionary)* -- *7. 1905 "He took up something of a liquid or smally divided nature which must be contained in a basket." P. E. Goddard, Morphol. Hupa Language 34*